# How to close <IMG> tags and add ALT text with Regex & WebStorm

Tags: html, regex, webstorm

I am having to edit a large number of HTML files (produced by an email generator) that contain code that doesn't pass the validator.  In particular, there is a large number (hundreds) of `<IMG>` that need to be closed (`<IMG/>`), and a large number missing ALT text (but some already contain ALT text).  I am using WebStorm 10 and my thought was to do the search and replace with regex, but I'm not that skilled at it, so am banging my head a big.

I got this far:

search for

```
 (<img)([^/>]+)(>)
```

and replace with

```
$1 $2 alt="" /$3
```

but this gives me duplicate ALT text if the tag already contains an ALT text, and in that case, it adds an extra "/" inside the IMG tag, just before the ALT.  I also want to make sure if the IMG tag *is* closed that it doesn't get an extra "/".

So if I have something like

```
<img  src="foobar.jpg" width="108" height="71" style="display:block"  >
```

I want to get

```
<img  src="foobar.jpg" width="108" height="71" style="display:block" alt=""  />
```

(but if the tag has an ALT or is already closed, leave it alone)

I spent an hour on this and solved much of the issue, but it's not perfect and doesn't work in the cases just above.  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try first dealing with adding `alt` into all tags and then finish with your regex for closing them? I belive this can be done in one regex, but you know the saying "Once a man had a problem he thought he can solve with regex... now he has two problems".

Comment: Don't do this with regex...

Comment: I stumbled at figuring out a regex to add alt tags where there were none.

Comment: If I weren't to do it with regex — what's the alternative?  To hand edit thousands of lines of code?  The regex I've got works pretty well, just not perfectly — I'm open to any suggestions…

Comment: If `alt` is a required attribute ... IDE may offer some help. Try running `Code | Inspect Code...` on such file and see if light bulb (quick fixes) will be available for `img` tags. And yes -- regex is a dangerous road to go as it's very easy to shoot in a foot and make mistake.

Comment: Thanks — Code | Inspect Code does a good job of finding missing alt tags — but there doesn't seem to be an automated way to correct them.  It doesn't find unclosed img tags —

Comment: And yes, regex is tricky, especially since I don't use it often.  But again, thousands of errors, so I don't know what choice I have — to edit each img tag by hand seems torturous.  There must be a way.

Comment: *"but there doesn't seem to be an automated way to correct them"* http://postimg.org/image/66bwlo4jx/ -- It should .. but it does not work (throws internal error in latest EAP build) -- need to try stable version.

Comment: *" It doesn't find unclosed img tags"* I do not remember such inspection either. What doctype is it?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: 1) With adding missing `alt=""` -- I may only suggest to click on result entry which will get you into correct position in editor .. and invoke quick fix menu (`Alt+Enter`, same as on screenshot). unfortunately group quick fix does not work for some reason (I guess it because it normally asks what text would be entered inside alt attribute (which supposed to be different for all/most of the images) .. and you cannot provide such value in bulk actions (except, maybe, empty value))

Comment: 2) I've tried multiple doctypes .. and none have triggered inspection for missing closing tag. So I guess there is no such inspection at all. 3) Based on the above the regex may indeed be the best option if such replacements need to be done often and/or in many files. I've tried few approaches in regex ... but none were "stable" enough -- few steps left or right (while still having valid img overall) and it stops working... I doubt I will be of any help here now.